# backbone.js initialize listeners vs events

Tags: events, backbone.js, view, listener

I don't understand the difference between putting a "click" listener in an initialize function  inside a view and putting it in the events object in the same view. They both listen for DOM events and trigger functions, right? What's the difference?

for example:

```
var ViewName = Backbone.View.extend({  
    initialize: function(){  
        this.$el.on("eventName", this.functionName, this)  
    },  
    functionName: function(){  
        //whatever  
    }  
});
```

versus:

```
var ViewName = Backbone.View.extend({  
    events: { "eventName": "fucntionName" }   
    },  
    functionName: function(){  
        //whatever  
    }  
});
```

Comment: `this.on("eventName", this.functionName, this)` doesn't listen to DOM events at all so your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Well... okay then what does it do? I've literally done the code school course 4 or 5 times and I don't get it. You can't just put "click" as the event in the first one? What about if it was this.el or something?

Comment: Backbone's events (http://backbonejs.org/#Events) aren't the same as jQuery's events. You could `this.$el.on(...)` but that would break if someone used [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement).

Comment: @EricHannum i think you organize your events at single point. When you go and refer for any event, you don't need to look all over your view where the event is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you do:

```
var ViewName = Backbone.View.extend({  
   initialize: function(){  
      this.$el.on("eventName", this.functionName, this)  
   },  
   functionName: function(){  
    //whatever  
   }  
});
```

You have to manually unbind the event when the view is being removed. So, you would have to do something like:

```
var ViewName = Backbone.View.extend({  
   initialize: function(){  
      this.$el.on("eventName", this.functionName, this)  
   },  
   functionName: function(){  
    //whatever  
   },
   remove: function() {
      this.$el.off("eventName", this.functionName);
      Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this, arguments);
   }  
});
```

If you use the `events` hash, Backbone takes care of undelegating events when the view is removed. This is all explained in [this section of the Backbone.js annotated source](http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-130).